# Receive in C++ a Java generic object as a method return type using JNI

Tags: java, android, c++, generics, java-native-interface

I have a C++ wrapper that calls Java functions of a Java SDK using JNI.

In the Java code there is a generic class, for example let's call it **MyClass**, that is defined like this:

```
public class MyClass<T> extends HashMap<String, T> {
    ...
}
```

In the C++ code I am calling a Java function using JNI, for example let's call it **getMyClass**, that is defined like this:

```
public MyClass<String> getMyClass() {
    return myclassObject;
}
```

So, the Java function getMyClass returns an object of type MyClass and I'd like to read this object in the C++ code where it is returned.

I tried casting the returned Java object with JNI's parameter type **jobject**, but it doesn't seem to work as it always has a null value. In other words, I tried something like this which would work if the returned object Java was of type String for example.

```
auto jObjectMyClass = (jobject) env->CallObjectMethod(jObjectThatHasGetMyClassFunction, getMyClassMethod);
```

**Questions:**

1. Is there any other casting that I could try when receiving the Java object in the C++ code, in order for this to work in a similar way?
2. Is there any other better way in which I should approach this matter of receiving a generic class object using JNI?

Comment: I don't understand your questions. There are no generics once you make it to JNI ("type erasure"). There is only `MyClass` where all `T`s become `Object`. Your `CallObjectMethod` should return valid `jobjects` unless the corresponding Java method also returned `null` OR you have a pending JNI error.

Comment: @Botje so what you mean is that in this case it's correct for CallObjectMethod to return jobject and if not then maybe, another error exists in the jni code. If so, then I will investigate this further and update with any info I find.